# play framework 2 - static methods

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm a java developper for some while.
Recently I've started working with play framework (in java, not scala) and what I like about it the most, is the stateless application type.
The question I have right now is :

- since play framework is stateless, can we use static methods everywhere (without having the risk that a user use some information of another user for instance ?) or the static methods in play is the same as static in a ordinary java application.
  The JVM server side keeps the same info as a classic web application ? 
  It may be a dumb question but thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a dumb question. You could theoretically use all static methods but it is not a good coding practice. Instead you can use something like domain objects that you pass around your program. You can change the data in a domain object as it is passed around and it only exists for the life cycle of your current execution stack (that is of course unless you persist it).

This will keep your program stateless and prevent you having to use all static methods.